# How can I create a bulk node creation interface?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a request for an interface where nodes with a small amount of required fields (for example, a title, date, and a node reference) would be able to be created in bulk on one screen.

I am imagining some kind of editable table view/grid with each row representing an individual node.

What would be the best approach to implementing something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Multi Node Add](http://drupal.org/project/multi_node_add) module might provide what you need.

Comment: I was in the process of writing up the code approach, but this option seems a lot more user friendly so I will only complete my answer if there is a specific request for it.

Answer (score 2):

This is great... there is a D6 & D7 version http://drupal.org/project/slickgrid

Edit: I highly recommend trying this its the most awesome thing!!  You even get your field widgets in popups when clicking on the cells.

A couple quick tips (D7) Be sure to also install http://drupal.org/project/title so you can reset the title (make it a field), Basically with this editor you can only edit actual fields, so same goes for location module, you'll need to use the field option rather than node option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `devel` module and in sub module exist another module  named `Devel generate` you can use it to genereate bulky , content type , vocabulary, taxonomy and ....

This is perfect way to create bulk, it also support local module